# iPhoto - add time to photo time

Tags: iphoto

I have taken some photos from a recent vacation, but forgot to set the "away" time, so the time is slightly off. Thats not much of an issue since its only an hour from my home time, but my partner also took photos, but she was smart enough to adjust the time, so when merged together the overlap is annoying. Is there an easy way (preferably in iPhoto) to adjust the time that the photos were taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for iPhoto '09. Select the pictures you want to adjust the time for. Go to Photos -> Adjust Date and Time… . Adjust the time there and all the pictures will be adjusted as you would expect.

[image: iPhoto Adjust Date and Time]